# Node.js Express - best way to avoid starting a server twice besides port conflict

Tags: node.js, http, tcp, locking, port

So I am creating a user-land library for Node.js and the library contains a server. It's possible for the user to issue a command that would start the server twice - but the server doesn't need a restart, it just needs to be started once. I want to minimize the amount of time the user has to wait for the library to tell the user that the server is already listening on port X, because this may happen a lot, because the library always needs to check if the server is already live. I could wait for the system "already listening" error, but is there a way to fail faster than that? Is there a way to lock some other resource, what is the best way to do that?

*Note that this would always be a server running on localhost.*

I have found that the tcp-ping library is pretty quick to determine if the server is available or not.

```
const tcpp = require('tcp-ping');

tcpp.probe(server.host, server.port, function (err, available) {

     //callback always seems to fire within 10ms...

    if(err){

      //some crappy error

    }
    else if(available){
         //server is live

    }
    else{
        // server is not live

   }


});
```

is the tcp-ping library probably pretty much the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always keep an `.server_status` file on some location to indicate the server is up.

Just need to look for it when starting (and exit if it exists), create it when you start the server and delete when the server is brought down. This approach is used by many applications